# Using Controller component of react-hook-form doesn't allow custom Antd Select to show label

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, react-hook-form

I'm using **Antd [`Select`](https://ant.design/components/select/)** component to build a  custom component which gives me the ability to return an object instead of a primitive value and show nested value in object item in the select dropdown options, it works fine and it can be validated using [`react-hook-form`](https://react-hook-form.com/) :

```js
<Form.Item ... >
  <SpringSelect style={{ width: "200px" }} options={departments} placeholder="Department 2"
            name="department2"  onChange={e => {setValue("department2", e);}}/>

</Form.Item>
```

This also works with [`Controller`](https://react-hook-form.com/api#Controller) component however ***it doesn't show the label*** inside the select input :

```js
<Controller as={<SpringSelect style={{ width: "200px" }} />}
            placeholder="Department 1" name="department1" options={departments}
            onChange={([e]) => {return { value: e };}} control={control}      />
```

for more details check the whole code in the codesandbox playground

[image: Edit proud-wildflower-3gndt]

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is due to your SprintSelect `innerProps`

have a look my CSB below:

https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-platform-tlr55

```
<Select onChange={props.onChange}>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and thanks that you pointed me to the issue origin, however in this case i can't get back the selected object

Comment: what do you mean get back the selected object?

Comment: by default the antd select return a selected value not a whole object

Comment: you can do the following? <Controller onChange={() => { return value; }} />

Comment: `<Controller onChange={(value) => { return value; }} />` what's return is up to you right?

Comment: first,the `value` parameter should be wrapped by `[]`, second, the `value` is just a property of my object not the whole object, with my code above the select returns the right object but it doesn't shows the label inside the select input

Answer (score 2):

When the component is inside the controller a `value` prop is send to it. And your are just deleting the `onChange` and `onBlur` from the props.

`Select` will use this prop value, but it's a object, that is why it doesn't show the label.

To fixed you can just delete `delete tmp.value;` before add the props to `innerProps`

Exemple: https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-river-8r4dt

I place a `console.log`, as you can see `department1` has a `value` field